# JavaScript - Convert an awkward string to a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, type-conversion

I'm having the issue of converting the following (string) to a date using Javascript:

```
2nd June 2018
```

This string is created by another system of which i have no control over other than javascript, in essence i need to convert this string to a date in order to add days on i can display the following example:

2nd June 2018 - 9th June 2018 etc

Unfortunately i have no way around this other than making the conversion,

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this already in date format? What do you want to achieve. provide some samples (example) and your own attempt code

Comment: Yes please provide some more examples. Is it entered by the user manually or by some other source?

Comment: It's currently a string, i need to convert it to a date so i can make calculations/add days et

Comment: There are a huge number of questions here already on how to parse a timestamp. The answers are the same: use a library with a parser (there are many good ones, many much smaller than moment.js) or write a function to parse your particular format. The second option is maybe 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using moment.js it's easy. Also all your calculations you have to make will be much easier using moment.js...

```js
let d = "2nd June 2018";
let m = moment(d, 'Do MMMM YYYY');
console.log(m.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: moment is love. moment is life

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a go now :)

Comment: According to the [*moment.js documentation*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), The parse token for the day number is wrong, it should be "Do", not "DD".

Answer (score 1):

check this

```js
    console.log(new Date("2nd June 2018".replace(/(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)/, "$1")));
```

Comment: This might work, but don't do this, you know what they say... "You got a problem? Use regex! Now you got 2 problems". Moment.js is fairly small (16 kb) and can help with dates throughout your project and in case your source changes the way it returns dates, you can quickly adapt to their changes.

Comment: 16kb is not small

Comment: Parsing of formats other than those noted in ECMA-262 is implementation dependent, hence the usual advice is to not use the built-in parser.